# Timestamp doesn't print in my template

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to call the `timeStamp` but it doesn't appear in my table. Here is my code:

```
  @foreach($cevents as $cevent)      
           <tr >
                 <td class="col-lg-2">

                              {{ $cevent->name_client }} 
                              </a>
                              </td>
                              <td class="col-lg-2">

                                 {{ $cevent->name_event }}
                              </td>
                              <td class="col-lg-4">

                               {{ $cevent->details }}
                              </td>

                              <td class="col-lg-3">

                             {{ $cevent->created_at }}
                              </td>

                         </tr>
                            @endforeach
```

Using `dd()` in a controller I can find it, so the value is present.

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is a `</a>` in the first table cell which doesn't belong there.

Comment: Cannot reproduce here. Working fine with me

Comment: Where do you call `timeStamp`?